# C# asp.net Regular expression for the formats value, *value, value* and *value*

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

In .net I want to write a regular expression for an input which accepts following 4 types

```
1) value
2) *value
3) value*
4) *value*
```

Here value is a combination of digits and alphabets eg: aa123, 123aa, ab12ba a12a33. The value can also be only letters or digits like AABB, 1234, etc., The letters include both capital and small letters

Comment: ... and what have you tried?

Comment: `^\*?[a-z0-9]+\*?$` ?

Comment: Which regex language?

Comment: @hperboreus can you modify it so that no other wild cards are accepted in between first * and last * and it should also accept capital letters and value can be either combination of both letters and digits or only digits

Comment: @hugh bothwell I tried for normal value which won't accept any wild card searches ^\*{0,1}(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^#$%^&amp;*()']*\*{0,1}$

Comment: In your examples above, is '*' a literal asterisk character or an "anything" wildcard?

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell '*' is a wild card

Comment: Hi with help from here I got one expression ^\*?[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^#$%^&amp;*()']*\*?$ but it is accepting wild cards in between like *12@34* it shouldn't accept any wild cards in between two *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl regular expressions, I'd use

```
^\*?\w+\*?\z
```

- `\w` matches word characters, which includes letters and digits.

---

But that matches a little more than what you requested. To match what you requested, one would use the following:

```
^\*?[\pL\p{Nd}]+\*?\z
```

- `\pL` matches letters.
- `\p{Nd}` matches digits.

---

Both of the above will match `*é*`. If you only consider a-z, A-Z and 0-9 to be letters and digits, you can use the following instead:

```
^\*?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?\z
```

Answer (score 0):

regex is a state machine here ya go [image]